# Display grid of images in an Array SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I can't use VGrid because unfortunately my deployment target has to be iOS 13.
This is what I came up with, but it's not working.

```
 @State var photoIndex = 0

 func displayPhotoPreview() -> some View {
        self.photoIndex += 1

        print(photoIndex)
        return PhotoPreview(url: photos[self.photoIndex].urls.regular)
            .onTapGesture {
                isPresented.toggle()
                self.selectedPhoto = photos[self.photoIndex]
            }
    }
```

```
 ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                ForEach(0 ..< photos.count / 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { _ in
                            if self.photoIndex < photos.count {
                                displayPhotoPreview()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(20)
                .sheet(item: $selectedPhoto) { selectedPhoto in
                    PhotoDetail(photo: selectedPhoto)
                }
            }
```

The print statement prints each number 30 times (there's thirty images)

Comment: Somewhat related, you start by increasing photoIndex meaning you never access the first image at index 0 and if your code had worked properly you would have gotten a crash when you tried to access index 30 at the end

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You can see there is an `if` to check that actually

Comment: @George_E and you can see that it doesn’t work since photoIndex is updated _after_ the `if`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ah yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the `@State` variable `photoIndex` 30 times (since there are 30 images). You will have also probably got the following runtime warning:

> Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

To fix this, just get the index by calculating it out from the index of the `ForEach`s.

Remove the `photoIndex` state variable. Code:

```
ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    ForEach(0 ..< photos.count / 3, id: \.self) { row in
        HStack(spacing: 15) {
            ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) { column in
                displayPhotoPreview(at: row * 3 + column)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(20)
    .sheet(item: $selectedPhoto) { selectedPhoto in
        PhotoDetail(photo: selectedPhoto)
    }
}
```

```
func displayPhotoPreview(at photoIndex: Int) -> some View {
    print(photoIndex)
    return PhotoPreview(url: photos[photoIndex].urls.regular)
        .onTapGesture {
            isPresented.toggle()
            self.selectedPhoto = photos[photoIndex]
        }
}
```